# Instability from Firefox after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, firefox

When I drag a tab out of Firefox from my one desktop to another, the system locks up, and takes me back to the login screen after 10-15 seconds.

I just updated my Intel NUC system from 22.10 to 23.04
It all worked just fine a week ago, on 22.10
It is a two monitor setup, both running at 1920 x 1080

Any ideas would be appreciated. My work around is to launch a new window, and drag that across, which does not result in the same behaviour.

Ubuntu 23.04 64 bit
Firefox 113.0.1
Intel_R_ Client Systems NUC7i7BNH (Intel® Core™ i7-7567U)
Intel® Iris® Plus Graphics 650 (Kaby Lake GT3e) (KBL GT3)
Gnome 44.0 Wayland WS

Comment: You can look at the final log entries of the previous boot with: `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Does this workaround (snap to apt version of firefox) help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: Thanks, @ArchismanPanigrahi,  This did fix the dragging issue.  The apt installed version of firefox seems to be somewhat unstable though.  Random tabs with spinning wheels and no content, usually followed up by Firefox not responding at all and needing to be killed, so I'm not sure I'll be able to keep using it.  I'll give it a couple of days and see if it gets better or worse.